# Got "filename.settings cannot be locked because it is read-only" error running iReport 4.0.2 at Ubuntu

Tags: ireport, jasperserver

I just installed iReport yesterday and it was working fine. But when I try to run it today it is not working properly.

Here is what I have done;

1. Downloaded iReport-4.0.2
2. Extracted it in my downloads folder
3. Try running though terminal

   1. `adm@linux:~/Downloads/iReport-4.0.2/bin$ sudo ./ireport`

      this gives the No protocol specified error in terminal.
   2. `adm@linux:~/Downloads/iReport-4.0.2/bin$ ./ireport`

      without `sudo`, this show many error messages in terminal and starts iReport. But again shows popup several errors. Still I cannot create or edit reports.

Here are the errors. I can post the output in terminal if needed. But its quite lengthy.
[image]

I also tried moving the iReport-4.0.2 to the `/opt/` folder. Even that resulted the same thing.
Also my JasperServer is up and running. But when I run a report it returns the following error;

```
com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser
```

Do not know whether there is any connection between these two issues.

Comment: ,Have you checked folder permission & its owner ?and why you are not using latest edition of iReport/Jasperserver

Comment: I couldn't find the latest version of iReport to run in ubuntu. I'll reply again once I check the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

$ sudo chmod 775 -R iReport-4.0.2/

if don't work you should use "sudo" to open iReport

$ sudo ./ireport

Regards

Yusuf Firdaus

Answer (score 0):

you must login with root user in terminal  means

$ sudo su

Enter password

After that run the ireport